# isSkipSelf Error WITHOUT firing HTTP Get in Ionic 2

Tags: http, ionic2

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null
```

After firing the Http get request the above error is returned. The code is below:

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/weekview/weekview.html',
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

@Injectable()
export class WeekViewPage {

    http: any;
    nav: any;

    constructor(http: Http, nav: NavController) {
       this.http = http;
       this.nav = nav;

       this.http.get("URL?username=jsmith&age=21")
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data.json()));
        }, error => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
        });
   }
}
```

I used the example parameters from the google apps script tutorial: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#url_parameters

In the browser I tried to use the same URL and returned the expected results:

```
{
  "queryString": "username=jsmith&age=21",
  "parameter": {
    "username": "jsmith",
    "age": "21"
  },
  "contextPath": "",
  "parameters": {
    "username": [
      "jsmith"
    ],
    "age": [
      "21"
    ]
  },
  "contentLength": -1
}
```

I've searched for many HTTP tutorials on ionic2 but some has different versions of code so I tried mixing them up with no success. Please help.

*Note: for security purposes, here's a public URL that I created to be used only for testing re this question/topic: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz8Uch1TJ2PfCCMJSEBmbAXhKD-_DagFesbDWKWlTSups-9Zt4/exec

EDIT: This is the code where isSkipSelf still exist: plnkr.co/edit/EkGuHtJ1IpRBJ4gcTiAZ

Comment: I saw above that you import the map operator but you are not using it. Could you try maybe call .map(data => data.json()) before the subscribe and see what happens?

Comment: @DenkoMancheski ~ I tried `http.get("URL?username=jsmith&age=21").map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });` but with the same error regarding isSkipSelf...

Comment: I tried making a request like this:
  this.http.get('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbz8Uch1TJ2PfCCMJSEBmbAXhKD-_DagFesbDWKWlTSups-9Zt4/exec?username=jsmith&age=21')
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data, "data");
      })
without mapping it to JSON. The problem is that it did not return JSON but html for some reason. Here is what it returned http://pastebin.com/gC8UQzbh

Comment: My bad I thought it was a rest URL I didnt see the headers of the "website". I cannot see which is the server url to receive the json so..

Comment: @DenkoMancheski ~ I don't know why but even if I commented out the line which contains http.get I still get the error `isSkipSelf`...

Comment: code with light explanation and some errors: http://plnkr.co/edit/EkGuHtJ1IpRBJ4gcTiAZ

Comment: and I don't know why but in here: "http://plnkr.co/edit/eDqT2bwlAL1q9QHQWkrE" I get a hint that says `Property 'http' does not exist on type 'WeekViewPage'.` and `Property 'data' does not exist on type 'WeekViewPage'.` while in this example: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/no-provider-for-http-ionic2-alpha-42/39169 they are not declaring anything...

Comment: you cannot expect to get a json from that URL because its returning html.. the JSON is just a string on the html.. thats why I wrote in the above comment that I did not see that its a website.. Try using postman and you will see that it returns html.. have you tried calling completely different endpoint and see what happens ? like this random endpoint: http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?firstName=John&amp;lastName=Doe

Comment: @DenkoMancheski ~ how did you made the get request??? I'm quite successful on my HTTP setup... but I'm having a problem with "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present" problem... how did you get passed that???

Comment: Try with the cors plugin for google chrome.. Also you need to setup your server to allow cors.. there is node module for nodejs that I know, but i am not familiar with the other ones.. If you cannot touch the server than you can try to use reverse proxy (nginx is great for this) so your request will be on the same domain but nginx will proxy it to the real server

Comment: Thanks... I had it "fixed" now... using  --disable-web-security flag...

Comment: Please don't add [Solved] to the title, but post an answer containing the solution instead, preferably adding a source and explanation. :)

Comment: will do... thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

I had it "fixed" now... using --disable-web-security flag...